# VS code error occurs even when using the correct SQL syntax

Tags: sql, mysql, visual-studio-code

```
ALTER TABLE users 
MODIFY COLUMN email VARCHAR(32) COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci NOT NULL;
```

VS Code underline `MODIFY` and `(32)` but in phpMyAdmin`s SQL command prompt it works properly.

If I write `ALTER` insted of `MODIFY`, there is no red underlining, but MySQL causes an error because it's the wrong SQL syntax.

Comment: can you elaborate what you are doing in vs code?

Comment: Does VSCode know you're using MySQL?  It may be analyzing the code based on SQL Server instead.  You may need to find and install an IDE extension for MySQL.

Comment: @David I use extension that makes you chose what type of DB I work with

Comment: I'm having the EXACT same issue. `syntax error at or near "alter"localhost`